# Can we prioritize devices connected to a Router

Tags: router, qos, rate-limiting

If a number of devices are connected to a router, can we prioritize them (PC - 1, Mobile - 2, Laptops - 3) by giving their MAC addresses.

That way if everybody is working, depending upon their priority, overall speed is divided and priority 1 will get the maximum speed in scenario where simultaneously all devices are downloading something 
Here are the Specs_--
network device -- Tp-link td-W8901N

Comment: What kind of "router"? Router are layer 3, Mac addresses are layer 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways of doing this. I will try to give you some ideas:

- you can tag your IP traffic with QoS attributes based on MAC address and apply traffic shaping on your router. This has to be done by the switch but you need a managed switch for this.
- put your clients on different subnets and apply traffic shaping policies on your router.
- you could put your client on different VLANs based on their MAC addresses and apply traffic shaping policies to different VLANs on the router.

Note, that it all depends on what switches/routers you have. You may not be able to do it at all if your hardware is not adequate.

Comment: Depending on the router, he also might do policy routing and QoS based on the MAC address of the station. Although this is violating the OSI model layer isolation premise, certain implementations (e.g. netfilter-ebtables setting MARKs along with `tc` QoS policies sorting market packets into a given flow) allow this to be done. But it arguably would be much easier to hand out different ranges of IP addresses by the DHCP server and do create QoS rules for the respective IP range.

Comment: Yes, DHCP is another option. Good point.